# What is the differences between Records, Class, and Units/Module in Pascal

Tags: class, records, delphi

i had struggle over those 3 things in pascal and for some reason i find them quite simillar and i didnt know in what kind of condition i should use them.

does records just like how do we record file? like array does?

and for units, i find some samples that shows me units are just like a basic formulas about something and we can reuse or calls them on the main program and uses the formulas/units by some variable we created?

pls let me know more about those. I'm very new to pascal and for some notes the other language i know is C#(basic).
Thank You.

Comment: You find records, classes and units quite similar? Then you really have a problem. What are you using to learn Pascal? Do you know any other languages?

Comment: i knw some basic of C#. and for pascal i just started. personally in C# i dont even really knw about classes. and i searched that theres no records in c# sofar.

Comment: in C#, records are called structs (and in some cases, unions).

Comment: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Record http://wiki.freepascal.org/Class http://wiki.freepascal.org/Unit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming

Comment: "classes" exist in Object Pascal (object oriented extensions to Pascal) but not "plain" Pascal. If you aren't familiar with classes at all (either in your study of C# or C++ or other object oriented language) you need to learn the basics of that first. A `record` is just a single structure used as a data type that contains one or more data items that can be of various types (and they can even be records, so you can have records inside of records). Look up what a "class" is, it's quite involved. And a Unit/Module is a way to organize a set of functions, data, and classes for a program.

Comment: thank you! i thought theres no records in c#. so its just the way the call it as structs.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are using some version of Object Pascal.

In the case of a record and a class, the two are very close to being the same thing. A class is effectively a record that allows the definition functions that operate on the class.

In C++ a record is a a struct and a class is also a class. However, in C++ a struct and a class are absolutely identical. In Object Pascal's they are not identical but are similar.

A module is a unit of compilation. A module can define classes and record.